Why am I getting an update#setState message in in Cmp when I check the node.js version after installing it?
I installed node.js recently and when I tried to check the version of it using the node -v command , the cmp shows me a message saying update#setState idle while opening up Visual studio code.
why is this happening and how do I solve it?
I need to know why does this happen and how to solve this?
